# Authentication by extending User model in DRF (Django Rest Framework)

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-rest-framework, token

I already have a working auth.token registration using the django default User class, but i was asked to add a new field to the User, i investigate things as AbtractUser, AbstractBaseUser, etc. And i think the best solution will be the OneToOneField "method".

This is what i tried to do:

models.py:

```
class Usuario(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    es_tecnico = models.BooleanField(name = 'es_tecnico', default = False, blank = True)
```

serializers.py

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username',
                  'password')

class UsuarioSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Usuario
        fields = ('user',
                  'es_tecnico')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        """
        Overriding the default create method of the Model serializer.
        :param validated_data: data containing all the details of student
        :return: returns a successfully created student record
        """
        user_data = validated_data.pop('user')
        user = UserSerializer.create(UserSerializer(), validated_data=user_data)
        usuario, created = Usuario.objects.update_or_create(user=user,
                            es_tecnico=validated_data.pop('es_tecnico'))
        return usuario
```

views.py:

```
class UsuarioViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    lookup_field = 'id'
    serializer_class = UsuarioSerializer
    queryset = Usuario.objects.all().filter(es_tecnico = False)


class TecnicoViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    lookup_field = 'id'
    serializer_class = UsuarioSerializer
    queryset = Usuario.objects.all().filter(es_tecnico = True)
```

I want to make it work as simple as possible, this is what i get when i use the command "python3 manage.py makemigrations":

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/stalker/PycharmProjects/ingSoft/servidor/virenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/stalker/PycharmProjects/ingSoft/servidor/virenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 365, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/stalker/PycharmProjects/ingSoft/servidor/virenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/stalker/PycharmProjects/ingSoft/servidor/virenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 332, in execute
    self.check()
  File "/home/stalker/PycharmProjects/ingSoft/servidor/virenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/home/stalker/PycharmProjects/ingSoft/servidor/virenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 351, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/home/stalker/PycharmProjects/ingSoft/servidor/virenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 73, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/home/stalker/PycharmProjects/ingSoft/servidor/virenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/checks.py", line 29, in check_user_model
    if not isinstance(cls.REQUIRED_FIELDS, (list, tuple)):
AttributeError: type object 'Usuario' has no attribute 'REQUIRED_FIELDS'
```

When i try solutions from others stackoverflow questions, i get this error:

```
AttributeError: type object 'Usuario' has no attribute 'USERNAME_FIELD'
```

if there is a simple way insted using OneToOneField i will apreciate it

This are the views where im having problem right now:
views.py:

```
class Registrar(mixins.CreateModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    serializer_class = UsuarioSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        #  Creando un nuevo usuario
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        user = Usuario.objects.create_user(username, email, password)
        user.save()

        token = Token.objects.create(user=user)

        return Response({'detail': 'El usuario fue creado con el token: ' + token.key})


class LoginView(mixins.CreateModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    serializer_class = LoginSerializer

    def create(self, request):
        serializer = LoginSerializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.validated_data["usuario"]
        django_login(request, user)
        token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
        return Response({"token": token.key}, status=200)
```

Comment: In `settings.py` file are you setting `AUTH_USER_MODEL` config var?

Comment: I already have an AUTH_USER_MODEL = pedidos.Usuario

Comment: pedidos.Usuario is not a valid User model so "AUTH_USER_MODEL = pedidos.Usuario" must be removed from your settings. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model

Comment: i had a line of coude undeleted, now when i one to register an user i got this error in the API: 'Manager' object has no attribute 'create_user'. If you can provide one link to a usefull post or documentation for people with the same problem i will help a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here in your case you are just [extending Django `User` model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model), so you should not override `AUTH_USER_MODEL`.

Delete this line of code from `settings.py` file: `AUTH_USER_MODEL = "pedidos.Usuario"`
, and in your code if you want to use your `User` model, this is the one you should use:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

(as we said you are just extending Django `User` model) or you can use the convenient function [`get_user_model()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.get_user_model)

> get_user_model():
>
> Instead of referring to User directly, you should
>   reference the user model using django.contrib.auth.get_user_model().
>   This method will return the currently active user model – the custom
>   user model if one is specified, or User otherwise.

If you want to get the attribute `es_tecnico` of a `User` you can use:

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> u = User.objects.get(username='Juan')
>>> juan_es_tecnico = u.usuario.es_tecnico
```

or using `get_user_model()`:

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
>>> my_user = get_user_model()
>>> u = my_user.objects.get(username='Juan')
>>> juan_es_tecnico = u.usuario.es_tecnico
```

**Edit:**

```
class Registrar(mixins.CreateModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    serializer_class = UsuarioSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        #  Creando un nuevo usuario
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        user = User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)
        user.save()

        token = Token.objects.create(user=user)

        return Response({'detail': 'El usuario fue creado con el token: ' + token.key})
```

In `Registrar` class use `User` model instead of `Usuario`.

I hope this will help.

Comment: I understeand, but the thing is, i need to user Django Rest Framework, if i add some new "Usuarios" with django Admin and my view's queryset ask "bring me all the "Usuarios where "es_tecnico = True", it works, my problem here is that i cant find the way to serialize this "Custom Users" with DRF

Comment: @JuanEsteban your serializers `UserSerializer` and `UsuarioSerializer` looks good, what the problem? again `Usuarios` is not custom user is just extended user  (called profile model). See [extending the existing user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model)

Comment: I edited the question, at the end i added the views that worked fine before i extend the django user class

Comment: @JuanEsteban for clarity what is the problem or errors that you get right now?

Comment: Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value: 'Manager' object has no attribute 'create_user'

Comment: @JuanEsteban have you **done** the steps in the answer? you deleted this line from `settings.py` file `AUTH_USER_MODEL = "pedidos.Usuario"`? otherwise if you want to create a custom user, you doing it the wrong way?

Comment: yes i deleted everything since "get_user_model()" to "AUTH_USER_MODEL = "pedidos.Usuario". That worked because i could not even run the server. But i cant find the solution for that error when i try to register a new user with the API, and everything works if i use django admin, but i need to use Django Rest Framework, no django Admin

Comment: For example, when i call the view that brings me all the user with es_tecnico = True, it works, because it bring me the users i created with django admin. To resume everything, i need to register (create) a new extended user with Django Rest Framework and "rest_framework.authtoken.models" without django admin framework interfering

Comment: Ok, in Register form you have the `es_tecnico` field? or you want to set it to a default value or what?

Comment: Your solution worked, it bringed me a new error "given username must be set", but i could fixed it changing " username = request.POST.get('username') password = request.POST.get('password')" to " username = request.POST.get('user.username') password = request.POST.get('user.password'). I love you man

Comment: Cool. Happy coding ;)